# Do minimal surfaces imply minimal volume?

Tags: minimal-surfaces

I have a set of non-intersecting (approximate) minimal surfaces derived from a parametrization of a gyroid that I've cropped & capped the ends, see image below for 3d print of some of them.

Am I right in assumiing that, in my case, given a minimal surface between a set of boundaries I will also get the minimal volume?

[image]